# How can I change the value of a variable while debugging?

Tags: linux, gdb

I know that I can output the value of a variable using

```
(gdb) p var_name
$1 = "varvalue"
```

Is there a way to set the value of a variable while debugging with gdb? The document that I'm using doesn't seem to have this command.

**Edit**

I've since learned that I can change the state of objects in memory by simply calling their functions! So to modify an object of type `std::string`, just call the `assign` function as follows:

```
(gdb) call str.assign("New Value")
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Google is your friend:

> For example, if your program has a variable width, you
>   get an error if you try to set a new value with just `set width=13',
>   because GDB has the command set width:

```
(gdb) whatis width  
type = double   
(gdb) p width $4 = 13  
(gdb) set width=47  
Invalid syntax in expression.
```

> The invalid expression, of course, is `=47'. In order to actually set
>   the program's variable width, use

```
(gdb) set var width=47
```

You can find the needed information in the [following document](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gdb/gdb_118.html):

Comment: Thank you for this answer! I just tried this with a double variable and it worked, however it didn't work with std::string objects. Is a similar technique to modify std::string objects as well?

Comment: check those out: http://sepwww.stanford.edu/public/sep/claudio/Research/Prst_ExpRefl/ShtPSPI/intel/idbe/10.1.015/doc/idb_manual/common/idb_the_assign_and_the_set_variable_commands.htm

Comment: and this one: http://rsquared.sdf.org/gdb/iacv.html

Answer (score 2):

A little bit later but to set a string variable you should try this>

gdb set var string_variable = 'new_string_variable'

Character numbers must be the same for the two variable definitions, in order to apply the change as appropriate. Quotes need to be applied to new variable.